# Story about apprentice wizard self-teaching magic, based on a comic series

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

The details that I remember about this book. It was based on a comic series. The beginning involved an inept young apprentice who wasn’t very good at magic. During an attack on his masters tower he is teleported to safety with a magic book. Figuring that the reason for the attack on the tower was to acquire this grimoire he must teach himself magic in order to survive on his own. I have already looked at Raymond Feist's magician series and that’s not it. Have had no luck with search engines so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like [Fortress in the Eye of Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/57017.Fortress_in_the_Eye_of_Time) by C. J. Cherryh.

[image: Fortress in the Eye of Time]

The apprentice is *Tristen*. He is a *shaping* i.e. a being called into existence by the wizard Mauryl. The shaping was only partially completed and the first few chapters are full of descriptions about the mistakes Tristen makes because he doesn't fully understand what it is to be human.

Tristen is given the book you refer to by Mauryl:

> Mauryl caught his sleeve, compelling his attention to a small codex Mauryl had pulled from among the parchments. Mauryl pressed it into his hands and folded his fingers over the aged leather.
>
> “Here is the answer, boy. Here is your answer to all your questions. Here is the way. Learn it. Study it. Become wise.”
>
> Tristen opened the book to its center. Its pages were thick with copywork, a bold and heavy hand that was not at all like the writing on the parchments Mauryl trampled underfoot, not written in the delicate, rapid letters Mauryl used.

After the attack on the tower Mauryl disappears and Tristen is left with his book:

> If, he thought, if he could have read the Book Mauryl had given him, he might have prevented the ruin that had taken Mauryl from him. But he had not been able. Mauryl had known his inability.

However he is not teleported away from the destroyed tower. He sees a vision of Mauryl telling him to leave and he walks away.

Also as far as I know the Fortress books weren't based on a comic or adapted into a comic.